# Node http server doesn't listen when started in worker using cluster

Tags: node.js

Reading online examples and NodeJS docs I wrote following script:

```js
import * as path from "node:path"
import { fileURLToPath } from "node:url"
import { createServer } from "node:http"
import cluster from "node:cluster"

async function primary() {
    console.log("Starting Primary Worker")
    const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))
    cluster.setupPrimary({ exec: __dirname + "/index.mjs" })
    const workers = []
    const promises = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const worker = cluster.fork(process.env)
        workers.push(worker)
        const promise = new Promise(res => worker.on("exit", res))
        promises.push(promise)
    }
    await Promise.all(promises)
    console.log("Primary worker exited")

}
async function worker() {
    console.log("Starting Worker", cluster.worker.id)
    const server = createServer((req, res) => { res.end("Hello, world!") }).listen(3001)
    console.log("Are worker server listening?", server.listening)
    console.error("Worker", cluster.worker.id, "exited itself =(")
    process.exit(1)
}
if (cluster.isPrimary) await primary()
else if (cluster.isWorker) await worker()
```

But, `createServer(...).listen()` doesn't do anything at all and I do not get any errors.
Here it is my log:

```
> node ./index.mjs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Starting Primary Worker
Starting Worker 1
Are worker server listening? false
Worker 1 exited itself =(
Starting Worker 2
Are worker server listening? false
Worker 2 exited itself =(
Starting Worker 3
Are worker server listening? false
Worker 3 exited itself =(
Primary worker exited
```

Every worker just exits.
I tried different ports without success.
What am I missing?

`node: v20.5.1`
`OS: Linux 6.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call server.listen(3001), it starts the server asynchronously, and the server is likely still setting up when you check the 'server.listening' property immediately after the listen call. This is why you are seeing false for the listening property. Also In your worker code, you are calling process.exit(1) outside the server's callback, immediately after starting the server. This is causing the worker process to exit immediately after the server was started, before it had a chance to listen for incoming requests. Try something like this instead,

```js
// if it is your intention to kill the worker thread after sending "Hello, world!" response. 
async function worker() {
   console.log("Starting Worker", cluster.worker.id)
   const server = createServer((req, res) => {
       res.end("Hello, world!")
       // Close the server after sending the response, 
       server.close()
   })

   server.listen(3001, () => {
       console.log("Worker server listening on port 3001")
   })

   // Handle the server close event to exit the worker
   server.on('close', () => {
       console.error("Worker", cluster.worker.id, "exited itself =(")
       process.exit(1)
   })
}

// if it is your intention to keep the worker alive..
async function worker() {
   console.log("Starting Worker", cluster.worker.id)
   const server = createServer((req, res) => {
       res.end("Hello, world!")
   })

   server.listen(3001, () => {
       console.log("Worker server listening on port 3001")
   })

   // Keep the worker alive until the server is closed externally
   server.on('close', () => {
       console.error("Worker", cluster.worker.id, "exited itself =(")
       process.exit(1)
   })
}
```

Comment: .listen() should prevent process from exiting according to docs. I also tried .ref() with no luck.

Comment: anyway probably you're right I don't need process.exit